# Limit content length in BBCode

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

Currently, we are using the following Code to replace the `[b]...[/b]` BBCode with `<b>...</b>`:

```
$s = preg_replace("/\[b\]((\s|.)+?)\[\/b\]/", "<b>\\1</b>", $s);
```

If the content between the Tags is too big, the PHP-FPM child crashes with a segfault. Since we allow our users to write large enoughs texts to cause this, we need some way to stop PHP from attempting to replace it if the content between the tags exceeds a certain length.

If there is another solution, please suggest it. Our current memory limit for a script is 128M, which should be enough. The maximum allowed post length is 50000 characters.

Comment: Why the  `( \s | . )+? ` for content ?

Comment: Use `/(?s)\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/`  or `/(?s)\[b\](.{1,500000})\[\/b\]/`. There is no need for double capture groups either.

Comment: A simpler way is   `$s = preg_replace( '/\[(\/?b)\]/', '<$1>', $s);`

Comment: Well the code this is from is ancient and I have rather bad experiences with changing it. I am using `/\[b\](.+)\[\/b\]/` now and the problem does not seem to persist anymore and from a certain length on, the BBCode is simply not parsed. Could anyone explain why?

Comment: What do you mean by "not parsed". That phrase has nothing to do with regular expressions.

Comment: the best way is to do that: `$s = strtr($s, ['[b]' => '<b>', '[/b]' => '</b>']);`, no need to check if tags are closed or not.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that it is completely ignored and the preg_replace does not change the text starting from a certain content size.

Comment: What that means is that the regex _does not match_ the source string, nothing else. You should debug print the source string (to a file) to find the real problem.

Comment: @sln: if the backtracking limit is reached, nothing is replaced, the replacement is aborted, you can know that with `var_dump(preg_last_error());`

Comment: I read that in an answer to another question. Yet, I am wondering why it did not happen before and the php child died with a segfault before.
And why is there no need to check wheter or not tags are closed?

Comment: @Kazuo `.` does not match newlines. That's why it did not crash/match in the second time. `\s` does match newlines, that's why the author grouped them into `(\s|.)` to match anything. Basically you could have used `.` with the `s` modifier to shorten your regex and make it cleaner.